# present perfect or simple present

Tags: grammar

Would I rather say:

She has stopped because she is tired.
She has been swimming for over an hour.

or

She stops because she is tired.
She has been swimming for over an hour.

Thanks in advance

Andi

Comment: Some more context would be helpful. Both of them are okay, but largely in different situations.

Comment: When you make these statements, has she already stopped, or is she in the process of stopping? Or are you describing her general behavior?

Answer (score 2):

First compare the two sentences, what meaning do they convey?

```
She has stopped because she is tired.
```

At the time of speaking she is no longer swimming. She has stopped. The sentence can be used if she stopped recently, but is also valid for some short time afterwards. If she stopped yesterday we would say.

```
 She stopped because she was tired.
```

Now this sentence is much more immediate:

```
 She stops because she is tired.
```

We would use it in situations where we are describing current events.

```
 He shoots, he scores!
 She takes her eyes away from the cooker and the food burns.
 He drops the glass and it smashes
```

So now look at the combination of the two sentences in your examples

```
 She has stopped because she is tired. She has been swimming for over an hour.
```

Feels slightly wrong to me. "She has been swimming" feels as though, right now, she is still swimming; but "She has stopped" implies that the action of stopping is not quite immediate.

```
 She has stopped because she is tired. She **had** been swimming for over an hour.
```

Whereas

```
 She stops because she is tired. She has been swimming for over an hour.
```

feels very natural. Imagine a sports commentator saying that line exactly at the instance that the swimmer stops.